# List files not matching given string in filename

Tags: ls, filter

I have a directory in which lots of files (around 200) with the name `temp_log.$$` are created with several other important files which I need to check.

How can I easily list out all the files and exclude the `temp_log.$$` files from getting displayed?

#### Expected output

```
$ ls -lrt <exclude-filename-part>
-- Lists files not matching the above given string
```

I have gone through `ls` man page but couldn't find anything in this reference. Please let me know if I have missed any vital information here.

Thanks

Comment: in BASH, `ls --hide='temp_log.$$'` should work. You could/should also extend this with wildcards, depending which part of the whole term `temp_log.$$` is.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With GNU `ls` (the version on non-embedded Linux and Cygwin, sometimes also found elsewhere), you can exclude some files when listing a directory.

```
ls -I 'temp_log.*' -lrt
```

(note the long form of `-I` is `--ignore='temp_log.*'`)

With zsh, you can let the shell do the filtering. Pass `-d` to `ls` so as to avoid listing the contents of matched directories.

```
setopt extended_glob          # put this in your .zshrc
ls -dltr ^temp_log.*
```

With ksh, bash or zsh, you can use the ksh filtering syntax. In zsh, run `setopt ksh_glob` first. In bash, run `shopt -s extglob` first.

```
ls -dltr !(temp_log.*)
```

Comment: Please, not single quotes in the example for GNU ls:
ls -I 'temp_log.*' -lrt
They are necessary to pass pattern to the command and not let the shell expand it.

Comment: On Ubuntu bash v4.3.48, it should be `-Itemp_log.*` without any space after the `-I`

Comment: @YanKingYin No, it's fine to have a space after the `-I`. However, the `*` needs to be quoted one way or another. `-I temp_log.*` doesn't work but `-I 'temp_log.*'`, `-I "temp_log.*"`, `-I temp_log.\*`, etc. are fine.

Comment: Just a side note: for multiple files, consider using multiple `-I` parameters. Generally, a simple ignore expression (example, `-I '*.jar'`) works fine. But making `-I` accept an explicit list of files to ignore is hard. Say I must ignore `xyz.jar` and `abc.exe`, while reporting all other files in the directory. Then `ls -I '(xyz.jar|abc.exe)'` doesn't work. But multiple `-I` parameters work very well:   `ls -I xyz.jar  -I abc.exe`.

Comment: BTW, `man ls` did not say much about regex support, but then I saw RMS (Stallman) wrote my version of `ls`. So I checked `info ls` which states: `‘-I PATTERN’ ...  ignore files whose names match the shell pattern (not regular expression) PATTERN`.  :-)

Answer (score 14):

You can use `grep` with the option `-v`.

```
ls -lrt | grep -v <exclude-filename-part>
```

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted, it's the correct answer.

Comment: Doing a grep on ls output is not always correct and is not recommended. It has side effects. Not able to recall exact issues. Side note - down vote was not from me ;)

Comment: Here's the link as to [why parsing ls is a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find` for this:

```
find . \! -name 'temp_log*'
```

This will just print the names, you can add `-ls` to make a `ls -l` style output with timestamp and permissions, or use `-exec ls {} +` to actually pass to ls with whatever options you want for columns, sorting, etc.

I wrote this assuming this was just files in a directory. If the directory contains other directories, you may want to avoid recursively listing them

```
find . \! -name 'temp_log*' -maxdepth 1
```

And if you use ls you'll want to pass the -d option to stop *it* from listing inside the directories: `-exec ls -d {} +`

Comment: Probably want `-maxdepth 1` as well to mimic non-recursive `ls`.

Comment: Nice.  Users who have a more minimal POSIX `find` without `-maxdepth` [should look here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/135943).

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use a feature of the shell, not of `ls`. I use bash, so I checked for what you want in [`man bash`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#EXPANSION). Search for "^EXPANSION", (by first pressing '/'). Excerpt:

> ### EXPANSION
>
> Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into words.  There are seven  kinds  of  expansion
>          performed:  *brace expansion*,  *tilde expansion*,  *parameter and variable expansion*, *command substitution*, *arithmetic
>          expansion*, *word splitting*, and *pathname expansion*.
>      ︙
>      ... < snip > ... 
>      ︙
>
> #### Pathname Expansion
>
> After word splitting, unless the **-f** option has been set, **bash** scans each word for the characters **`*`**, **`?`**, and **`[`**.  If one
>          of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a *pattern*, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted  list
>          of  file  names  matching  the  pattern.  …

I've recently started excluding files based on their first letter, with a command like:

```
$ ls ./[^t]*
```

This would match anything that doesn't start with the letter `t`. If you add more characters between the brackets, then you exclude files starting with those letters too.

Looking for a link, and I've a good one! See [Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching). From there, this would work for your case:

```
$ ls -lrt ./!(temp_log.*)
```

This requires that the `extglob` shell option is enabled
using the `shopt` builtin (`shopt -s extglob`), as stated by [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/51981/80216#51991).

Answer (score -1):

Just do

```
ls -ltr `grep -il patterntosearch  *`
```

Comment: `grep` searches for a pattern within a file, rather than in the file name.

Answer (score -2):

Since the files that you **DONT** want printed have "temp_log." in the filename, then filter out with grep:

```
ls -lrt | grep -v "temp_log."
```

NOTE: The other post with a similar answer probably got downvoted because the user didn't include quotes " " around the string that grep should be looking for. Without the the quotes, it doesn't work as advertised.

Comment: Your 'NOTE' is not strictly correct.  There are certain characters that might need to be quoted, but I don't think there are any in that particular string.

Comment: until there's a user or group named "temp_log" (the dot in regex would match a space or anything following `temp_log`. This is not a good (general) way to exclude `ls` results.

Comment: only with `-F`, @smokes2345; a period will match any character in a basic regular expression. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/117549